# Most efficient way to upload image to Amazon S3 with Python using Boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I'm implementing Boto3 to upload files to S3, and all works fine. The process that I'm doing is the following:

I get base64 image from FileReader Javascript object. Then I send the base64 by ajax to the server, I decode the base64 image and I generate a random name to rename the `key` argument

```
data = json.loads(message['text'])
dec = base64.b64decode(data['image'])
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('bucket_name').put_object(Key='random_generated_name.png', Body=dec,ContentType='image/png',ACL='public-read')
```

This works fine but respect to performance, is there a better way to improve it?

Comment: Please be specific and clarify "but respect to performance".

Comment: The one optimization I can think of is to stream the data but I don't know if boto3 supports reading a buffer directly. It does however support reading from a file so you could open a fifo, decode into that and pass it to boto. This way it would be an in-memory file-like buffer that streams the data through.

Comment: Can someone add Client side code for the upload it could be in react or plain jquery also. IT would be useful for the users

Answer (score 4):

I used this and I believe its more effective and pythonic.

```
    import boto3
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = 'your-bucket-name'
    file_name = 'location-of-your-file'
    key_name = 'name-of-file-in-s3'
    s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket, key_name)
```

Comment: Isn't this less efficient? You have to write the data into a temporary local file, that means dealing with IO overhead

Comment: @JaviOverflow, you are not writing to a local file. You are pushing an existing file on your local system to s3. Do you understand? Please explain the issue better if the answer is not sufficient.

Comment: The OP has the data loaded in memory so in order to use your solution he would have to write it down to a local temporary file which translates into IO overhead. Isn't it?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @JaviOverflow use `upload_fileobj` instead of `upload_file` instead

Comment: I voted it down, because `upload_fileobj` or `put_object` is better in this case

Answer (score 3):

To upload an in-memory image directly to an AWS S3 bucket, as @Yterle says, **[you should use `upload_fileobj`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/upload_fileobj.html)** (which is accessible from the lower-level `boto3.client` interface rather than its higher-level wrapper, `boto3.resource`.)

```py
import io
import json
import base64
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

BUCKET = "bucket_name"
IMAGE_KEY = "random_generated_name.png"
MESSAGE = {"text": {"image": IMAGE_B64_BINARY_DATA}}

data = json.loads(MESSAGE["text"])
dec = base64.b64decode(data["image"])
# Transform the binary data into something
# which can be used like a file handle
image_filelike = io.BytesIO(dec)

# Upload in-memory object to S3 bucket
s3_client.upload_fileobj(
    Fileobj=image_filelike,
    Bucket=BUCKET,
    Key=IMAGE_KEY,
    ExtraArgs={"ContentType":"image/png", "ACL":"public-read"},
    Callback=None,
    Config=None)

# Optional: wait until the s3 object exists before exiting
s3_resource.Object(BUCKET, IMAGE_KEY).wait_until_exists()
```