# How I can upload batch images with name on Amazon S3 using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am uploading images to a folder currently on local . like in site/uploads.
And After searching I got that for uploading images to Amazon S3, I have to do like this

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# Get list of objects for indexing
images=[('image01.jpeg','Albert Einstein'),
      ('image02.jpeg','Candy'),
      ('image03.jpeg','Armstrong'),
      ('image04.jpeg','Ram'),
      ('image05.jpeg','Peter'),
      ('image06.jpeg','Shashank')
      ]

# Iterate through list to upload objects to S3   
for image in images:
    file = open(image[0],'rb')
    object = s3.Object('rekognition-pictures','index/'+ image[0])
    ret = object.put(Body=file,
                    Metadata={'FullName':image[1]}
                    )
```

**Clarification**

Its my code to send images and name to S3 . But I dont know how to get image in this line of code   `images=[('image01.jpeg','Albert Einstein'),`       like how can I get this image in this code from  /upload/image01.jpeg   .  and 2ndly how can I get images from s3 and show in my website image page ?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816346/most-efficient-way-to-upload-image-to-amazon-s3-with-python-using-boto3

Comment: @HassanAbbas  thanks for reply . As I will upload a image by getting from form . So what you recommend about this ?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you asking how to Upload images (as shown in your code), or how to Download images ("how I can get that images from that folder")? What have you tried and what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  sir question updated

Comment: Are you saying that `image01.jpeg` is actually located in `/upload/image01.jpeg` on your local computer and you want to upload it to `index/image01.jpeg` in the Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes exactly from local folder to s3 . using code

Comment: Why do you wish to use Python? If would be easier to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) as mentioned by @OpenBSDNinja below.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  I am doing that in Django . Like as a admin I will upload image on admin side which will be update on s3 .

Answer (score 3):

I know your question is specific to boto3 so you might not like my answer, but it will achieve the same outcome as what you would like to achieve and the aws-cli also makes use of boto3.

See here: http://bigdatums.net/2016/09/17/copy-local-files-to-s3-aws-cli/

This example is from the site and could easily be used in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#copy all files in my-data-dir into the "data" directory located in my-s3-bucket 
aws s3 cp my-data-dir/ s3://my-s3-bucket/data/ --recursive
```

Comment: I have a django website from where I will upload that image . That will automatically on Upload will be uploaded to S3

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I also work with Django. I would suggest that you look at one of the s3-django packages (there are quite a few) unless you have some reason why you can't use them. Here are a few that you can look at: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html  and this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-aws-s3-storage-backend-your-django-application-naved-khan/

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing, the code snippet you are showing as a reference is not for your use case as I had written that code snippet for batch uploads from boto3 where you have to provide image paths in your script along with metadata for image, so the names in your code snippet are metadata.So upto what i get to understand from your question, you want files in a local folder to be uploaded and want to provide custom names before uploading , so this is how you will do that.

```
import os
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

directory_in_str="E:\\streethack\\hold"

directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):

        strg=directory_in_str+'\\'+filename
        print(strg)
        print("Enter name for your image : ")
        inp_val = input()

        strg2=inp_val+'.jpeg'
        file = open(strg,'rb')
        object = s3.Object('mausamrest','test/'+ strg2)     #mausamrest is bucket
        object.put(Body=file,ContentType='image/jpeg',ACL='public-read')



    else:
        continue
```

programmatically , you have to provide path of folder which is hard-coded in this example in **directory_in_str** variable. then , this code will iterate over each file searching for image , then it will ask for input for custom name and then it will upload your file.

Moreover, you want to show these images on your website , so public_read for images have been turned on using ACL , so you can directly use s3 links to embedd images in your webpages like this one.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mausamrest/test/jkl.jpeg

This above file is the one i used to test this code snippet. your images will be availbale like this. Make sure you change bucket name. :)

Comment: Exactly I want this what you got from my question . So If I will send images path to s3 and names. that will uploaded on s3 and can be shown there ? or there just images path will be shown

Comment: and 2nd thing where I should put this code , and execute as I want this to run when I submit picture in form .

Comment: you will have to provide the folder path where your image lies in the **directory_in_str**  variable and your **s3 bucketname** , rest of all will be done automatically with my code, one by one original image name will be shown to you , then you will be asked for a custom name , after you input custom name , your image will get uploaded , after then next image's turn and this will go on until the last image in your folder has been uploaded

Comment: in your s3 bucket , all images will be shown with the name you provided to them while uploading

Comment: for the 2nd doubt, this is a server side script that will run on your django server.I have no experience with django , so can't help on how you will do that

Answer (score 1):

Using the Resource method:

```
# Iterate through list to upload objects to S3
bucket = s3.Bucket('rekognition-pictures')

for image in images:
    bucket.upload_file(Filename='/upload/' + image[0],
                       Key='index/' + image[0],
                       ExtraArgs={'FullName': image[1]}
                      )
```

Using the client method:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

...

# Iterate through list to upload objects to S3
for image in images:
    client.upload_file(Filename='/upload/' + image[0],
                       Bucket='rekognition-pictures',
                       Key='index/' + image[0],
                       ExtraArgs={'FullName': image[1]}
                      )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply john now in rosourse method how this for loop will know  that its my images located in that place ?

Comment: `Filename='/upload/' + image[0]` tells it to look for the local file in `/upload/`.

Comment: oh okay thanks . So I need to upload data of image . ? thank you really